# How to remove a UIButtons placed into scrollview via a for loop when a new array is chosen to be placed into that scroll view?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, xcode8

I need bit of help. Based on how far someone can throw a frisbee, I am using that value via a slider to copy an array of the recommendations I am giving them into the arrayToUse variable which creates the UIButtons with an image that I’m placing horizontally in the bottom of the VC using a scrollView. The user can again move the slider to select a different distance and hit submit and it will load a different array based on the new distance. My problem is that if they pick a new array with less images than the one they started with I don’t know how to dismiss the previous images. I can see it in the view debug hierarchy sitting under the top layers and it will still show as if there are more images they could possibly scroll to at the end of the scrollView because longer arrays are underneath.  Is there a way I can dismiss the previous array and load a new one when they hit the submit button?

```
for i in 0..<arrayToUse.count {

    let imageView = UIButton ()
    imageView.setImage(arrayToUse[i].image, for: .normal)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let xPosition = (self.view.frame.width - 60) * CGFloat(i)

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition + 30, y: view.frame.height - self.scrollView.frame.width + 30, width: self.scrollView.frame.width - 60 , height: self.scrollView.frame.width - 60)

    scrollView.contentSize.width = (scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)) - (CGFloat(60 * i))
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(discSelectionVC.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    imageView.tag = i

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am hearing this correctly I think this is what you want:

```
for subview in scrollView.subviews {

    if subview is UIButton {
        // Perform logic here to determine if you want to remove the UIButton from the view
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

This will loop through the subviews in your scrollView and then if it sees that the subview is a UIButton then based on the logic you write you can choose to remove or not remove that UIButton.

Comment: I did not add any additional logic to the code you provided,  it performs exactly what I was hoping it would do. Thumbs up sir.